# Refresh jQueryMobile page with php content after navigation

Tags: php, mysql, refresh, jquery-mobile

I have two jQueryMobile pages that contain PHP code as well. On page A I have a SELECT that shows content of a MySQL database. Page B offers the possibility to add data to the database. Now when navigating from page A to B (via changePage) and returning to page A with the "Back" button, the content of the SELECT is (of course) not refreshed.

What is the correct way to do this in jQueryMobile? The important thing here is that the PHP portion of the page needs to be executed and in turn the SELECT needs to be updated.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your first page which has the php to run would require

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#yourpageid", function() {
```

)};

This would only work if your php select was created by a jquery call. In my case i found creating jquery elements with php results was easier in the long run.

In my situation i have this.

```
  <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            $(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#index4", function() {
                                $(function(){
                                    var items="";
                                    $.getJSON("ajaxResponder.php?method=getContacts",function(data){
                                    $.each(data,function(index,item) 
                                    {
                                    items+="<option value='"+item.email+"'>"+item.username+"</option>";
                                     });
                                    $("#contacts").html(items); 
                                    $("#contacts").trigger("change");
                                    });
                                });
                            });  
                        </script>
                        <select name="contacts[]" id="contacts" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

Without any code example and how you have written your code this is my best answer.